# Crop text with tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

When text is long i am need to crop it and put at the end "...". And when i hovered text i need to show tooltip with fulltext.
I am writting function for it, but i create hidden elemen of DOM. Cropping i am doing with css. There may be a way easier?

My function determines text is crop or not. And then i choose display tooltip or not.

```
const isCropText = (text: string, maxWidth: number): boolean => {
  const hiddenDiv = document.createElement('div');
  hiddenDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
  hiddenDiv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  hiddenDiv.innerHTML = text;

  document.body && document.body.appendChild(hiddenDiv);

  const offsetWidth = hiddenDiv.offsetWidth;

  document.body && document.body.removeChild(hiddenDiv);

  return offsetWidth > maxWidth;
};
```

Comment: can't you use jquery tooltip or bootstrap tooltip?

Comment: No. Only native js or react. Or some light library:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with css:

```css
.tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #CCC;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.tooltip:hover {
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
</div>
```

Comment: tooltip like attribute "title"